# Hard convergence

Tags: analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of complex numbers. I need to prove that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{|a_n|^2}{n+1}\log^2(n+1)<\infty\Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1}\left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a_k}{n+k+1}\right|^2<\infty
$$
I used Cauchy-Schwarz, but without success. Can you help?